# Android findViewById is returning Null in Eclipse generated project

Tags: android

I created a new Android project in Eclipse with one Blank Activity.  In the fragment, I added a TextView called textHello.  All I want to do for this test is to modify textHello's text value.  But I'm my findViewById is giving me null.

Here is the fragment code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.gcuitest.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textHello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.gcuitest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView helloText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            //      .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); 
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        helloText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHello);
        helloText.setText("Gerard");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Why is findViewById giving me null?  Is it in the right place?  I've looked at other code samples, and they place findViewById in onCreate, after setContentView, which is what this does.  What did I miss?  Thanks.

Comment: delete R.java file.it'll generate automatically. & then run your project

Comment: if you want change value in fragment you must do that in fragment class, this layout that you post to us is not `activity_main`, this return NPE to you because you don't have `textHello` in `activity_main`

Answer (score 1):

> Why is findViewById giving me null?

Because `textHello` TextView is inside `PlaceholderFragment` layout instead of Activity which is `activity_main`.

if you want to access TextView from Fragment layout then use `onCreateView` as :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    helloText = (TextView)view. findViewById(R.id.textHello);
    helloText.setText("Gerard");

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I tried to put the findViewById inside onCreateView, but I got an error with findViewById: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity"  I updated the code above with the complete MainActivity.java file.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: @Gerard you must use `rootView.findViewById`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K, thank you.  I did that from inside the fragment, and it worked.  I understand now that I must intercept the view created by the Inflater, and do the findViewById against it.